# Remote access to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server

Reminder: Not on local area network. Is there a need some configuration of SQL Server? What connection strings will be used? C#.net is the programming language.

Comment: @JayRiggs ...  Nice... I needed a good laugh

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about c# or ms sql server 2008 however I have set up many servers

every computer connected to the internet has an address... I'm sure you know that
now, if you use a router you will know that the router is connected to the modem, and is distributed through the router either through a wireless connection or ethernet connection (the cord), the way the router organizes things, is each computer is assigned a private ip address (something like 192.168.1.2)... this private ip address cannot be accessed by the outside world at all... BECAUSE the router gets a packet, and doesn't know where to put it, so it immediatlely drops it (forgets it)


this is really safe, because this means the only way a bad person could reach your computer is if they were on the same network... however, sometimes you need to host a server that NEEDS to be accessed by the outside world...
this is explained in a bit, just read on

now also every internet packet (which is anything sent around a network) goes to a specific port

these are referenced with regular numbers: ie (port 80, 160, 55, et cetera)

the great thing about ports is that different computer programs can handle different ports, at the same time!!!

so a computer can be running multiple servers at the same time. because the corresponding packet is sent to the corresponding port and therefore a packets meant for a specific application won't interfere by another accidentally.

so in conclusion what we need to do is tell our router to say...

is the port equal to the port used in the ms sql server?

if so take the packet and send it to (the private ip address of your server)
this is called `Port Forwarding`

you'll need to first find the private ip address of your server.

on windows you would need to go in the command prompt and type:
`ipconfig`
in Linux and Mac OS X
`ifconfig`

once you find the private ip address of the server. make it a static... meaning it cannot change

you'll have to research this as I do not use Windows

remember: `Static IP Address`

now once you get a static ip address for your server you'll need the port(s) that ms sql server 2008 uses.

once you find that you need to set up port forwarding on your router

this varies from router to router, however, if you have a Netgear router you can go to the web admin page by pointing your browser to http://192.168.1.1/
this will bring you to the netgear router admin page. find port forwarding/port triggering on the sidebar and click add custom service, then add the input.

Now the last step is to find your public ip address, to tell your friend, this is the address he/she will access the server with

you can find this real easily by going to http://www.ipchicken.com/

this should work

HOWEVER

if you only have a modem and get your internet directly through that. you have a different situation

all the packets get sent to the one computer connected to WAN port (meaning everything gets sent to your computer regardless of port)...
if this is the case

you should forget about port forwarding and just give your friend your public ip found using ipchicken or another method....

this should work, unless ms sql has an extra security layer that I don't no about

hope this helped

EXTRA

Windows by default adds a firewall that blocks all connections, except for the exceptions that are established after a bit of use... so first you will need to punch a hole in Windows firewall by adding an exception... this is done by clicking on the current connection you are using and clicking on properties or something, don't know exactly but once you find out how to do that. it's just a matter of telling the firewall that port "whatever port ms sql uses" is safe.

After that is done, your friend should be able to connect by entering your ip address as the host.... I don't know much about C# as I said, but what your friend would do is use the nessecary procedures as he or she would have if they were connecting to any old sql server. except the "host" is the ip address of your server.


I don't quite know what you mean by connection string, could you try to give me more info on that please?

Comment: thank you so much sir, it helped a lot..im not using router it is directly connected to the modem..

Comment: @Angelo Serrano If windows firewall is turned on you'll have to open up the ports there as well (Maybe you remember SQL Slammer circa 2002). Also if you're looking for how to configure the port see [How to configure an instance of SQL Server to listen on a specific TCP port or dynamic port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938).

Comment: so how can i connect to my server using my desktop app?what connection string will i use? thanks 4 d help sir :D helped me much

Comment: @Angelo Serrano check out my new answer for more help...

Answer (score 0):

All SQL servers can connect over tcp/ip and MS is no exception.  If your machine is behind a NAT router or a firewall you need only setup the appropriate port access.  On most consumer grade equipment this is known as a pinhole.  You must allow inbound to the SQL Server port of 1433 or whichever one you choose.

**Most** ISP's these days give you one WAN ( real world ) IP address and that is the wan side of your router.  All machines on the LAN side are normally on a 192.168.x.x / 10.x.x.x / 172.16.x.x address scheme which are not routeable as all routers are programmed to ignore those address blocks and not to pass them on.

Please keep in mind unless you asked specifically for a static IP address your WAN side will most assuredly change from time to time and so you will need to let your friend know what it has changed to via something like ipchicken.com

Additionally since LOTS of attackers look on the standard ports for MS-SQL I highly suggest you use some random port above say 10,000 instead of the standard 1433 if your device does not have the ability to limit the source address.

Comment: do you have some samples how to do it?tut? thank you so much :D

Comment: Uhmm not really smaples per se but when you install SQL server one of the programs is the communications config tool wchi allows you to select things like tcp/ip, netbui, named pipes etc.  In the tcp/ip section you can choose the port. I noted above that you are directly connected to the modem.  That is kinda scary with a windows server man.  Just sayin.

Comment: why sir? for its okay because this is just a case study and implement this to show will it works that all sir. thanks 4 d help

Comment: A windows box *directly* connected to the internet with no firewall or at least NAT between it and the world will not last long.  I assume you have found the config tools yes?